# Bulk update of tables in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, bulk

I have a requirement where I need to make bulk updates to a table from a flat file in a Java program.

The flat file will have thousands of entries with Comma Separated Values. So if the entry in the flat file is found in table, I should update the row, else I need to insert it into another table. So I have written a function for the same. But my problem is updating the table at one go for all the entries in the flat file.

I have come across bulk insertion using SQL loader, but that cannot be used for updating the table.

I also used the JDBC batch update, but the problem is stored procedure/Function with `out` or `inout` parameters cannot be batched.

Can anyone suggest if there is a way to do this ?

Comment: Is your requirement really to update one table and insert into another?  Or is that a typo?

Comment: yes. I need to update a table if the condition matches, if not i need to insert the data into another table.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use a [external table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm) (referencing a file as a table) and then use a [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) command (a command that lets you do upserts) to update / insert my table

Comment: Hi , Thanks a lot for your reply.I tried the same example given in the tutorials.The first time I got some oracle exception like    "ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout" .So gave both the write and read permission for the directory which I created. I was then able to read the data. Then i changed the data in the input file and I am again getting the same error as above with a message "ORA-30653: reject limit reached". So will it only work if the input file does not change?

Comment: external table is like sqlloader, you can change the data but for a change in the structure you'll need a different description - in this case another external table.

Comment: thanks for the reply. It was because of the wrong format of data i had put in the data file. But right now i am facing an issue regarding the number of rows in the data file. If the data file has more than 61000 entries in it , I am not able to retrieve the data into a cursor in a procedure, or even do a select query to count the number of rows. It throws the following error

Comment: ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-30653: reject limit reached
ORA-06512: at "SYS.ORACLE_LOADER", line 52
29913. 00000 -  "error in executing %s callout"
*Cause:    The execution of the specified callout caused an error.
*Action:   Examine the error messages take appropriate action.        But the error will not be thrown if the entries will be less than 60000. What i am not really sure is that is it because the number of rows is exceeding some limit ? because the log file has a error which told something like below.

Comment: Fields in Data Source:

    MTOSI                           CHAR (500)
      Terminated by ","
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    AAC                             CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    PAC                             CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
    IAC                             CHAR (255)
      Terminated by ","
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader.             Does this mean error is with some record ?

Comment: I don't think that it is the amount of records. REJECT LIMIT is the amount of rejected records that should make the loading stop. There is probably a record which doesn't meet the structure. Try adding "REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;" to the definition and see if it works. if s it does, check in the log files (.bad, .dsc) which record was rejected

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
the PARALLEL option into documents says separate processing of the data files will happen after dividing the datafiles into chunks.Will the use of the PARALLEL option help in faster access to the rows of external table? 
I have right now divided the file into 3 different files and have mentioned the same in the external table definition. 
Then i run a procedure which access the data in external file using cursors to update the other table .But the time taken to update the table from the external table did not seem to improve.So how is Parallel option helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Google GORM its a bit more involved but you will write less code.